# I can't implement Reactive Repository with Elasticsearch in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, reactive-programming, reactive, spring-data-elasticsearch

Seems reactive repository are not supported by elasticsearch, but I need to try other way not two way below.

Way1 - https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/?fbclid=IwAR0fmVRA4NaWBem6sB9vLUsN6s5F3MCF2-10NIVsjQVqqJwrJ0PHrM73co8#elasticsearch.clients

summary: It's "ReactiveElasticsearchClient" and "ClientConfiguration" not found. (code below to edit)

Way2 - https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/#elasticsearch.reactive.repositories

summary: This code below.

```java
public interface ReactivePersonRepository extends ReactiveSortingRepository<Person, String> {
    Flux<Person> findByFirstname(String firstname);

    Flux<Person> findByFirstname(Publisher<String> firstname);

    Flux<Person> findByFirstnameOrderByLastname(String firstname);

    Flux<Person> findByFirstname(String firstname, Sort sort);

    Flux<Person> findByFirstname(String firstname, Pageable page);

    Mono<Person> findByFirstnameAndLastname(String firstname, String lastname);

    Mono<Person> findFirstByLastname(String lastname);

    Mono<Long> countByFirstname(String firstname);

    Mono<Boolean> existsByFirstname(String firstname);

    Mono<Long> deleteByFirstname(String firstname);
}

org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Reactive Repositories are not supported by Elasticsearch. Offending repository is com.example.reactive.repositories.ReactivePersonRepository!
    at org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport.useRepositoryConfiguration(RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport.java:382) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport.getRepositoryConfigurations(RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport.java:104) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate.registerRepositoriesIn(RepositoryConfigurationDelegate.java:145) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.AbstractRepositoryConfigurationSourceSupport.registerBeanDefinitions(AbstractRepositoryConfigurationSourceSupport.java:60) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.lambda$loadBeanDefinitionsFromRegistrars$1(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:364) ~[spring-context-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:684) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsFromRegistrars(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:363) ~[spring-context-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:145) ~[spring-context-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:117) ~[spring-context-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:327) ~[spring-context-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:232) ~[spring-context-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:275) ~[spring-context-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:95) ~[spring-context-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:705) ~[spring-context-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:531) ~[spring-context-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.java:66) ~[spring-boot-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:744) ~[spring-boot-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:391) ~[spring-boot-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312) ~[spring-boot-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) ~[spring-boot-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1204) ~[spring-boot-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at com.example.reactive.ReactiveApplication.main(ReactiveApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(AbstractRunMojo.java:543) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
2019-09-23 09:43:26.517 DEBUG 4314 --- [           main] onfigReactiveWebServerApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.AnnotationConfigReactiveWebServerApplicationContext@5adba8eb, started on Mon Sep 23 09:43:24 ICT 2019
[WARNING] 
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run (AbstractRunMojo.java:543)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Reactive Repositories are not supported by Elasticsearch. Offending repository is com.example.reactive.repositories.ReactivePersonRepository!
    at org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport.useRepositoryConfiguration (RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport.java:382)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport.getRepositoryConfigurations (RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport.java:104)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate.registerRepositoriesIn (RepositoryConfigurationDelegate.java:145)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.AbstractRepositoryConfigurationSourceSupport.registerBeanDefinitions (AbstractRepositoryConfigurationSourceSupport.java:60)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.lambda$loadBeanDefinitionsFromRegistrars$1 (ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:364)
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach (LinkedHashMap.java:684)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsFromRegistrars (ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:363)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass (ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:145)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions (ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:117)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions (ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:327)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry (ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:232)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors (PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:275)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors (PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:95)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors (AbstractApplicationContext.java:705)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh (AbstractApplicationContext.java:531)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.refresh (ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.java:66)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh (SpringApplication.java:744)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext (SpringApplication.java:391)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run (SpringApplication.java:312)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run (SpringApplication.java:1215)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run (SpringApplication.java:1204)
    at com.example.reactive.ReactiveApplication.main (ReactiveApplication.java:10)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run (AbstractRunMojo.java:543)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:834)
```

- edit

Spring Data Elasticsearch version 3.1.10 and Elasticsearch version 6.8.1

Configuraion for way1

```java
@Configuration
public class Config {
    @Bean
    ReactiveElasticsearchClient client() {

        ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration = ClientConfiguration.builder()
                .connectedTo("localhost:9200", "localhost:9291")
                .build();

        return ReactiveRestClients.create(clientConfiguration);
    }
}
```

Comment: which version of Spring Data Elasticsearch and Elasticsearch do you use? How do you set up the configuration?

Comment: Spring Data Elasticsearch version 3.1.10 and Elasticsearch version 6.8.1

Comment: If you mean configuration in way1, I'm editing post

Comment: can you please what you trying to do here and why you want to user elastic repo why not elastic rest client

Comment: I need to connect elasticsearch via reactive repo, because it's Non-blocking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reactive Repository interface is available in version 3.2 which currently is available from the milestones repository in version 3.2.0.RC3 or from the snapshots repository as CURRENT-SNAPSHOT where you have the doumentation link from.

3.2.0.GA is planned to be released next week on September 30th (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/wiki/Release-Train-Moore), then it will be available vie the normal maven repositories.

Elasticsearch 6.8.1 is fine for Spring Data Elasticsearch 3.2.0.GA

Comment: Thank you for your guidance.